# Placing the figure exactly at the top of the page in Latex

Tags: positioning

I have a problem in placing a picture into a page. I used a simple code as below:

```
\begin{figure}[t!]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[keepaspectratio, width=0.6\textwidth]{./pics/5_11}
  \caption{Number of RSUs that each vehicle has encountered}   
  \label{fig:RSUencountered} 
\end{figure}
```

The problem is that the picture is placed exactly in the middle, although I used position specifier (t!).

How can I instruct the latex to put the picture at the top of the page.

BTW: this picture is the only element in the page.

Comment: Page floats are handled differently. See [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/5764) and [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275/5764)

Comment: Do you have anything else on the other pages, or is your document just a single image that you want at the top of the page?

Comment: @Werner: yes. Its a 100-page document, and this figure is the last element in one of the chapters. Latex puts it on a separate page, but in the middle of the page!

Comment: What total portion of the page is the size of the float? 50%? 70%? 90%?

Comment: @Werner: I think its around 50 percent or less.

Comment: I assume you issue a `\clearpage` (or something similar) just before using `\begin{figure}...\end{figure}`, right? If this is the case, add `\mbox{}` (or `\null`) after the `figure` environment before starting a new `\chapter` and your alignment should be fixed. Since there's nothing else on the page, LaTeX centres it, since that would be the best way to present the information.

Comment: @Werner: No, unfortunately I have no \clearpage.

Comment: There must be other things causing this, and without a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/5764) that illustrates your problem it is difficult to assess what to do. As a last resort, issuing using `\clearpage\begin{figure}[t]...\end{figure}\null` should work. Are you able to reproduce the problem on a smaller scale using something like [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) for dummy text and (say) `\rule{.6\textwidth}{.5\textheight}` for your image?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The vertical spacing above the top floatpage float is defined by `\@fptop`.  The default value of this parameter is `0pt plus 1.0fil`. Hence when you have a single figure on a separate page you get white space on top. (Similarly `\@fpbot` is for bottom space with the value `0pt plus 1.0fil`. Hence you get white space on bottom also. And `\@fpsep` defines the vertical spacing between floatpage floats. The default is `8pt plus 2.0fil`).

To have the figure on top, you have to define `@\fptop` as

```
\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\makeatother
```

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
%
\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\makeatother
%
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t!]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[keepaspectratio, width=0.6\textwidth]{./pics/5_11}
  \caption{Number of RSUs that each vehicle has encountered}
  \label{fig:RSUencountered}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What the purpose of `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` command?

Comment: @MohammadFajar You can't use `@` in your preamble. It can be used only in a style file. For details see: [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351)