# Place image in top of page of book document

Tags: graphics, floats

I need to place an Image in top of book document. But thats image still placed in center document. This is my code:

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper  , 12 pt]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{package}
\usepackage[space]{grffile}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{E:/gambar tesis/variasi/9-2-10-cheek-kiss}
\caption{}
\label{fig:9-2-10-cheek-kiss}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\begin{figure}[htb]`

Comment: And I think you don’t even need the `figure` environment here. Do you need to refer to this image and nence set the empty `\caption` before the label?

Comment: @Speravir , this code auto-generated by TexStudio

Comment: @MohammadFajar: So, you do not need a reference to your image, do you? Clean up your example code. Also the needless `%\usepackage{package}`.

Comment: No, I using reference to that image. This is just example how my code looks like.

Comment: @HarishKumar , your solution not always works. It is works just for a simple page. In my current project thats not work.

Comment: Should this image appear before your titling or before a chapter? Or simply in a text. Perhaps you could add some example text … BTW better use an image from package `mwe`, and there are at least three packages for dummy text (`lipsum`, `kantlipsum` and `blindtext`).

Comment: There is nothing to discuss: Add more information into your question. Show reaction to comments and given answers.

Comment: I have meet the solution in this page:
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66252/placing-the-figure-exactly-at-the-top-of-the-page-in-latex/66270?noredirect=1#comment373336_66270