# Place table at top of the page

Tags: tables, floats

I want to place a table at the top of the page. I have tried using the answer provided here:

[Placing the figure exactly at the top of the page in Latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66252/placing-the-figure-exactly-at-the-top-of-the-page-in-latex)

However, this did not provide the expected response and the table remains below the top of the page.

[image]

```
 \documentclass[10pt]{article}

\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\setlength{\@fpbot}{0pt plus 1fil}
\makeatother


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{adjustbox}      
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}


\begin{table}[t!] \caption{This is a nice table} \label{tab:instruments}
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=1.5\textwidth, center }
   \begin{tabular}
      {p{5cm}p{2cm}p{5cm}p{1cm}p{5cm}} \hline Instrument & Resolution & Caption & Date & Figure \\   

\hline 

Speybroeck's X-Ray Telescope  &  10 & First X-Ray Images of the Sun  \cite{vanspeybroeck1970}  & 1970 & {\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{figure}}\\   

Brueckner Sounding Rockets &  No Data & Early observations of jets \cite{brueckner1983}  & 1983 & {\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{figure}}\\   

Yohkoh/SXT & 5   & Observations using SXT \cite{shibata1992} & 1992 & {\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{figure}}\\   

      SOHO & 2.5 & Description & Date & {\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{figure}}\\   

      Hinode/XRT & 1.028 & Description & Date & {\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{figure}}\\   

      STERO & 1.6   & Description & Date & {\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{figure}}\\   

      SDO/AIA & 0.6  & Description & Date & {\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{figure}}\\   

      Solar Orbiter (proposed) & 0.05 & Description & Date & {\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{figure}}\\   


          \hline
  \end{tabular}

\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: your table is to tall to be fit in one page.  this cause your problems with its placing on the top of a page. See, if the `longtable` solve your problem or split table manually into two parts

Comment: Don't use `adjustbox` with tables, they generally will become unreadable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See, if the following solution is acceptable to you:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}% <-- added option "export"

\usepackage{caption} % <-- added
\usepackage{siunitx} % <-- added
\usepackage{ragged2e}% <-- added
\usepackage{booktabs, 
            tabularx}% <-- added
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\setlength{\@fpbot}{0pt plus 1fil}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}     % <-- for dummy text
\usepackage{showframe}  % <-- to show page layout
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{teal}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
    \begin{table}[t!] 
    \centering
\caption{This is a nice table} \label{tab:instruments}
   \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}L S L l C@{}}
    \hline 
Instrument & {Resolution} & Caption & Date & Figure \\
    \hline
Speybroeck's X-Ray Telescope  
        &  10 
        & First X-Ray Images of the Sun \cite{vanspeybroeck1970}
        & 1970
        & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=m,margin=0pt 1pt]{figure}\\
Brueckner Sounding Rockets 
        &  {No Data} 
        & Early observations of jets \cite{brueckner1983}
        & 1983
        & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=m,margin=0pt 1pt]{figure}\\
Yohkoh/SXT 
        & 5
        & Observations using SXT \cite{shibata1992}
        & 1992
        & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=m,margin=0pt 1pt]{figure}\\
SOHO    & 2.5
        & Description
        & Date
        & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=m,margin=0pt 1pt]{figure}\\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
%
\begin{table}[t!]
\ContinuedFloat
    \centering
\caption{This is a nice table (cont.)}
   \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}L S L l C@{}}
    \hline
Hinode/XRT 
        & 1.028 
        & Description 
        & Date 
        & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=m,margin=0pt 1pt]{figure}\\
STERO   & 1.6   
        & Description 
        & Date 
        & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=m,margin=0pt 1pt]{figure}\\
SDO/AIA & 0.6  
        & Description 
        & Date 
        & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=m,margin=0pt 1pt]{figure}\\
Solar Orbiter (proposed) 
        & 0.05 
        & Description 
        & Date 
        & \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=m,margin=0pt 1pt]{figure}\\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

I split table manually to two parts, add packages `ragged2e` for better adjusting cells contents, `caption` for continuation of floats, `siunitx` for align numbers of resolution and `tabularx` for fit table in text width. With option `export` in package `adjustbox` are vertically centered images as well added top/bottom margins to them:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It works for me. The lesson I learned here is that I need to put `tabularx` inside `table`.

Comment: @Huyen, you are welcome!