# Figure placed at the middle of the new page

Tags: floats, positioning

Hello i have a problem to place the figures at the top of a page and i see this : [Placing the figure exactly at the top of the page in Latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66252/placing-the-figure-exactly-at-the-top-of-the-page-in-latex)
But i don't want to choose it , i want automatically when a figure is appeared at the newpage, because i have add something to my thesis, to be placed at the top now at the middle of the newpage.
Thank you in advance

Comment: your question is not clear ... please provide small complete document, which will show what you like to achieve. based on guessing, see, if the `\begin{figure}[ht] ... \end{figure}` what you looking for.

Comment: latex is smart enough to place the figures in the correct place and this placement will change when you introduce new text, so don't worry about this problem until you have everything finished.

Comment: @Ignasi Ok thank you. I thought i only have this problem.